# How to add text to a textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add a text to a text box but when I write `AppendText` an error occurs that says *`cannot convert from string[] to 'string'`*. Should I use another "`add` method" or can I remove the `[]` signs or what should I do?

```
private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxCategory.AppendText(new string[] {
              "Komedi",
              "Skräck",
              "Romantik",
              "Action",
              "Livsstil" });
         }
```

Comment: Are you trying this in WinForms, UWP, WPF, or Xamarin?

Comment: WinForms are used

Comment: If you look at the [official documentation of the TextBoxBase.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8) function you can see that it expects a single `string` as a parameter and not an array of `string`s. Just as the error tells you, it can't implicitly convert an array of strings to a single string.

Answer (score 2):

`AppenText()` uses `string` as parameter. So, you can either join this array into one string, like this:

```
string text = string.Join(",", new string[]{ "Komedi", "Skräck", "Romantik", "Action", "Livsstil" });
textBoxCategory.AppendText(text);
```

or pass string as parameter, like this:

```
textBoxCategory.AppendText("Komedi, Skräck, Romantik, Action, Livsstil" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant **add/append** `string array` to the textbox. You should convert it as `string` before appending, as below

```
private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxCategory.AppendText(string.Join(",", new string[] { "Komedi", "Skräck", "Romantik", "Action", "Livsstil" }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way, "create" strings first, couple of ways possible. String[] is an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays).

```cs
private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] stringArr = new string[] { "Komedi", "Skräck", "Romantik", "Action", "Livsstil" };
    foreach (item in stringArr)
    {
        textBoxCategory.AppendText(item );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply pass the strings of the array on after another:

```
(new string[] { "Komedi", "Skräck", "Romantik", "Action", "Livsstil" }).ToList().ForEach(str => textBoxCategory.AppendText(str));
```